# strange extra boxes in my HTML table on the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, row

At the bottom of the page I have a summary where a summary table is displayed.
Why do these additional boxes appear in my table? I don't really understand what they are generated from.
The view in my page:
[image: Text]

This is my HTML:

```html
<div class="overflow-auto">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <details>
                    <summary><strong>Matrice A di comparazione</strong></summary>
                    <td class="tabella">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                                <tr style="font-size: 20px;">
                                    <th scope="col">
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">MDC
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">EFF
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">CV
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">REV
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">SDC
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">EDI
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as r ">
                                    <th scope="row" style="font-size: 20px;">{{arrayStringhe[r]}}
                                    </th>
                                    <td *ngFor="let column of row; index as c">
                                        <select [(ngModel)]="oggetto[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)" *ngIf="r > c"
                                            style="font-size: 15px;">
                                            <option [ngValue]="a.num" *ngFor="let a of arrayComparazione">
                                                {{a.char}}
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                        <div *ngIf=" c >= r" style="font-size: 15px;">
                                            {{oggetto[r][c]}}
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row" style="font-size: 20px;">TOT
                                    </th>
                                    <td style="font-size: 15px;" *ngFor="let risultato of matrixRisultati">
                                        {{risultato | number: '1.2-2'}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </details>
            </div>
```

I checked the closure of the `div`, `td`, `tr`, but I don't understand how they are generated.
**Edit**

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (let r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
      this.matriceNormalizzata.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
      this.matrix[r] = []
      this.oggetto[r] = {}
      this.oggetto[r][r] = 1
      for (let c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
        if (r == c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(1)
          this.oggetto[r][c] = 1
        }
        if (r > c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(1 / 2)
          this.oggetto[r][c] = 1 / 2
        }
        if (r > c+1) {
          this.matrix[r].push(1 / 9)
          this.oggetto[r][c] = 1 / 9
        }
        else if (r+1 < c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(9)
          this.oggetto[r][c] = 9
        }
        else if (r < c) {
          this.matrix[r].push(2)
          this.oggetto[r][c] = 2
        }
        
      }
    }
    this.onSelectChange(0, 0)
  }
```

Comment: It seems like it depends on the value of "matrix". Could you add it to your question or, if it is dynamically generated, how it is generated?

Comment: you have a `<table>` **into** a `<td>` I suspect invalid HTML

Comment: @PedroLima I've edit the question